# Solving a recurrence relation in Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am learning about big O and recurrences.
I encountered a problem that mentioned,

```
t = { 0, n =1 ; T(n-) , n > 1 }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get to O(n^2) from this ?

Comment: I think your formula is flawed. Did you mean t = { 0 if n == 1 ; T(n-1) if n > 1} ? (though it's not O(n²))

Comment: The question as it is now is unsolveable. for starters, what is `T()` [note that this is not recursive equation, the left side of the equation is a constant `t` and not a function `T:N->N`]. What does `n-` mean? Please check your text book and bring the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functioin in your question have the complexity O(n) if it was O(n²) it should look like this:

```
T(x) = { 1, x =0 ; n + T(x-1) , x > 1 }
```

wheer n is the number of calculations for t(x) then x /= 0

Comment: For the function you provided, `T(x) =n^x`. You probably meant `T(n) = n + T(n-1)`, but it also could be `T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 1`, or infinite number of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I do no quite understand what you are trying to ask. But, typically, O(n^2) algorithms will feature the main operation being executed inside 2-Level nested loops. Like:

```
 for(a=0;a<5;a++) {
     for(b=0;b<5;b++) {
       /* Some of the main operations of the algorithm */
     }
  }
```

Similarly, 3-Level nested loops containing the main operations of the algorithm are likely to have complexity of O(n^3) and so on.

(Note: Exceptions may be there to the above methods)